# Using App Engine Standard with PHP7.4

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-app-engine-standard

I have Problems using php 7.4 with App Engine Standard. [The Documentation states there is an beta Version (php74)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref), but it does not work.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid runtime 'php74' specified. Accepted runtimes are: [php, php55, python27, java, java7, java8, go111, go112, go113, java11, nodejs10, nodejs12, php72, php73, python37, python38, ruby25]
```

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: php74

env_variables:
    ...
```

There is no difference in using `gloud beta app deploy --no-cache` or `gloud app deploy`, same error.

`gcloud -v`

```
Google Cloud SDK 294.0.0
beta 2019.05.17
bq 2.0.57
core 2020.05.21
gsutil 4.51
```

How can I get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

May I suggest that you try and [update your SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) version to the latest one[(296.0.0 as of 2020-06-09)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#29600_2020-06-09) by running `gcloud components update`, and then retry the deployment. It is highly likely that the version that you are using (294.0.0) may not be compatible with deploying PHP 7.4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I updated and did make sure with `gcloud version` that I'm on 296.0.0 but same error appears. 

I just found an Issue that describes my Problem, so I think there is no Solution and the docs are wrong? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156966373

Comment: and you are using `gcloud beta app deploy` right? You need to use that command as PHP 7.4 is still in Beta.

Comment: Yes, I use `gcloud beta app deploy` and `Invalid runtime 'php74' specified.` appears.

Comment: A [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/159492184) has been opened for this issue. Please "+1" yourself there as doing so will keep you posted on new developments.